# Django ORM - find objects that a variable fits inbetween a range of model fields?

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to find all django objects using an integer variable, where this variable is inbetween two django model fields. I understand using __range() is normally for finding if a model field is inbetween two variables, but I need it the other way around.

models:

```
class Location(models.Model):

     location_start = models.IntegerField()
     location_end = models.IntegerField()
     sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='sample_id')
```

views ( doesnt work) :

```
location_query = 1276112

loc_obj = Location.objects.filter(
              sample_id=sample_obj,
              location_query__range(location_start, location_end)

    )
```

Raw SQL:

```
SELECT *
 FROM location
 WHERE sample_id=12 
 AND 1276112 BETWEEN location_start AND location_end
```

Is there an easier way to do this without looping through the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to filter all `Location` objects with `obj.location_start < location_query < obj.location_end`. The filter statement for that would look like this:

```
loc_obj = Location.objects.filter(
              sample_id=sample_obj,
              location_start__lt=location_query,
              location_end__gt=location_query)

          )
```

If you want an inclusive range (`<=`), use `location_start__lte` and `location_end__gt=location_query`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this(using [gte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#gte) and [lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#lte)):

```
loc_obj = Location.objects.filter(
          sample_id=sample_obj,
          location_start__gte=location_start,
          location_end__lte=location_end
)
```